# How to solve this error ? menuAim is not a function

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

Error:

```
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (mega-menu.js:41:28)
    at fire (jquery.js:3238:32)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3368:8)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3588:14)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:3623:11)
(anonymous) @ mega-menu.js:41
fire @ jquery.js:3238
fireWith @ jquery.js:3368
ready @ jquery.js:3588
completed @ jquery.js:3623

Code:

$('.cd-dropdown-content').menuAim({
        activate: function(row) {
            $(row).children().addClass('is-active').removeClass('fade-out');
            if( $('.cd-dropdown-content .fade-in').length == 0 ) $(row).children('ul').addClass('fade-in');
        },
        deactivate: function(row) {
            $(row).children().removeClass('is-active');
            if( $('li.has-children:hover').length == 0 || $('li.has-children:hover').is($(row)) ) {
                $('.cd-dropdown-content').find('.fade-in').removeClass('fade-in');
                $(row).children('ul').addClass('fade-out')
            }
        },
        exitMenu: function() {
            $('.cd-dropdown-content').find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
            return true;
        },
        submenuDirection: submenuDirection,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load whatever plugin is reponsible for `menuAim`, you are trying to run a function that does not exist in this scope.

Comment: All the other content is workin just this portion is not working